# Is there any same php function of ignore_user_abort() in node.js?

Tags: php, node.js

I want to know if there is any same php function of ignore_user_abort() in node.js . This function leave a script running when someone close the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there is any same php function of `ignore_user_abort()` in node.js.

No. The behavior controlled by `ignore_user_abort()` -- terminating a script when its HTTP request is aborted -- doesn't exist in Node.

Comment: Ok! So there is no one equivalent ... I find out that I can use  npmjs forever, but I must change the application architecture a lot by using npmjs forever and do the job this way.